# can't intall any package for unkown reason!

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  avahi-utils ethtool fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core
  gnome-exe-thumbnailer icoutils ippusbxd libandroid-properties1 libappstream3
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2:i386 libasound2-plugins:i386
  libasyncns0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386
  libavahi-common3:i386 libbsd0:i386 libc++1 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386
  libcups2:i386 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
  libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexif12:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386
  libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libgcrypt20:i386
  libgd3:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386
  libglib2.0-0:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgmp10:i386 libgnutls30:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal:i386
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
  libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386 libhardware2
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386
  libhogweed4:i386 libhud2 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libhybris libhybris-common1
  libice6:i386 libicu55:i386 libidn11:i386 libieee1284-3:i386
  libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386 libjemalloc1 libjpeg-turbo8:i386
  libjpeg8:i386 libjson-c2:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms2-2:i386
  libldap-2.4-2:i386 libllvm3.8:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmedia1 libmpg123-0:i386
  libnettle6:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386
  liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386
  libpcap0.8:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libpulse0:i386
  libqcustomplot1.3 libqt5feedback5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5positioning5
  libqt5quicktest5 libqt5scintilla2-l10n libqt5test5 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsane:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsm6:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libspeexdsp1:i386
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 libsss-nss-idmap0 libstdc++6:i386
  libsystemd0:i386 libtasn1-6:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386
  libudev1:i386 libunity-action-qt1 libusb-1.0-0:i386 libv4l-0:i386
  libv4lconvert0:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx3:i386
  libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwrap0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libx86-1
  libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcomposite1:i386
  libxcursor1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386
  libxfixes3:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxml2:i386 libxpm4:i386
  libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
  libxt6:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-31
  linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72
  linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-72-generic ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 oxideqt-codecs
  p11-kit-modules:i386 plainbox-provider-checkbox
  plainbox-provider-resource-generic plainbox-secure-policy pm-utils
  pyotherside python3-checkbox-support python3-cups python3-cupshelpers
  python3-guacamole python3-jinja2 python3-padme python3-plainbox
  python3-xlsxwriter qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside
  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml-module-qt-labs-settings
  qml-module-qtfeedback qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects
  qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qtquick-window2 qml-module-qtquick2
  qml-module-qttest qml-module-qtwebkit qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts
  qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics qmlscene qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-dev-tools qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin
  qtdeclarative5-test-plugin qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin
  suru-icon-theme system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer ubuntu-mobile-icons ubuntu-ui-toolkit-theme
  vbetool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of adapta-gtk-theme:
 adapta-gtk-theme depends on gtk2-engines-pixbuf (>= 2.24.30).
 adapta-gtk-theme depends on gtk2-engines-murrine (>= 0.98.1).

dpkg: error processing package adapta-gtk-theme (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                            dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus-data:
 nautilus-data depends on dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend; however:
  Package gsettings-backend is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nautilus-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nautilus:
 nautilus depends on nautilus-data (>= 1:3.18).
 nautilus depends on nautilus-data (<< 1:3.19).

dpkg: error processing package nautilus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon:
 python3-aptdaemon depends on gir1.2-glib-2.0.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 (>= 1.1.1).
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-apt (>= 0.8.5~ubuntu1).
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-dbus.
 python3-aptdaemon depends on python3-gi.

dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dNo apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                   ependency problems prevent configuration of aptdaemon:
 aptdaemon depends on gir1.2-glib-2.0.
 aptdaemon depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu16~ubuntu16.04~ppa1); however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 aptdaemon depends on python3-gi; however:

dpkg: error processing package aptdaemon (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu16~ubuntu16.04~ppa1); however:
  Package python3-aptdaemon is not configured yet.
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on python3-gi; however:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on gir1.2-gtk-3.0; however:
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets depends on gir1.2-vte-2.91; however:

dpkg: error processing package python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 adapta-gtk-theme
 nautilus-data
 nautilus
 python3-aptdaemon
 aptdaemon
 python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I receive this error ,
I cant fix this

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: What did you do between when it used to work and now?